# Android fragments - replace is adding a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having a weird problem, and not sure why. I have a main activity with 2 fragments that split the screen. The left fragment will be static, but the right side needs to change layouts based on user actions.

I'm using REPLACE, but it's creating a new fragment right under fragment2 (right side) and then that is the one that seems to change.

I'm wondering if it's because in my Main activity I'm using `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
where the `Main.xml` is laying out Fragment1 and Fragment2?

So my question is: should I be adding my fragments programmatically instead of relying on the base layout?

I really would like to see an example of the best way to do what I'm trying to do.  All of the `ListFragment` examples I'm seeing online is not really doing what I need, because when you click on an item in the list, the other fragment is just displaying different content with the same layout.

Comment: Update:Here the code:
    // Now switch to the 3rd fragment layout
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
          
          Fragment3 fragment3=new Fragment3();
          
          // refer to the Content View of the Activity
          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment3, "fragment1");
          fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);          
          
          fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: What it's doing is adding the 3rd fragment below either the first or second fragment (whatever I'm telling it to replace) and I cannot figure out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace only dynamic fragments, not layout ones. So add your replaceable fragment from code.